# AMQ8594: WebSphere MQ commands are no longer available in /usr/bin

Tags: ibm-mq

After installing `mq v7.1` trial version (server) in `redhat` Linux I am not able to  run any `mq` commands like `dspmqver crtmqm`. I am getting the error bellow. Could someone please advise me in this regard.

```
AMQ8594: WebSphere MQ commands are no longer available in /usr/bin. 

In order to run MQ commands you must manage your path configuration as 

described in the WebSphere MQ product documentation. In particular review the

topic on "Choosing a primary installation".
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> In particular review the topic on "Choosing a primary installation".

If you follow the instructions in the MQ InfoCenter on "Choosing a primary installation" then everything will work just fine.  If you use Google then it would take you to: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/zi00700_.htm

Answer (score 0):

Run this command `setmqinst -i -p /opt/mqm` to set the primary installation.